# How do I stop the Linux terminal in Windows from making the error sound?

Tags: audio, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

If I'm in an empty Linux terminal in Windows (using the Windows Subsystem for Linux), and I hit backspace, I hear this annoying error-like sound. My Windows computer used to do this, but then I turned it off. How do I turn off this sound?

Comment: Do you have a link so I can better understand what that means? For everything I've been doing so far, it works just like a Ubuntu (which I think is a type of Linux) terminal.

Comment: Ubuntu is Gnu/Linux. But a lot of people are calling Gnu/Linux just Linux. Gnu/Linux is Gnu+Linux+X11+… Linux is the kernel, just a small part. The Free Software Foundation have been saying that we should call it Gnu/Linux for years, but most people think this is just them sulking because of lack of credit. However it is more a matter of practicality. What should you call it if you remove Linux (e.g. WSL, Cygwin, Gnu/Bsd, or …). Or what should you call it if you remove Gnu (e.g. android). And no it is not just like Ubuntu, there is much missing.

Comment: The link https://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.en.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Bash on Windows notification sound effect](https://superuser.com/questions/1108120/how-to-disable-bash-on-windows-notification-sound-effect)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to stop `bash` generating error sounds without affecting other Windows programs, type the following:

```
bind 'set bell-style none'
```

If you want a permanent change, add it to the end of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: This answer certainly works, but ewertonvsilva's suggestion to edit /etc/inputrc seems preferable unless your installation has multiple users.

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 5):

Here using the WLS (Ubuntu for Windows) I had to edit at:

```
/etc/inputrc
```

Just run it and restart the terminal

```
echo 'set bell-style none' >> /etc/inputrc
```

Comment: no permission even using sudo

Comment: @viniciusgati, that is probably due to the redirection in the command. You could use `sudo vi /etc/inputrc` (or using another text editor you like in favor of vi) to edit the file. Or check [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106663/how-to-run-a-command-that-involves-redirecting-or-piping-with-sudo) for more details about the problem and other solutions.

Comment: Both "# bell-style none" and "# bell-style visible" are already present in /etc/inputrc. Just uncomment the one you wish to use by deleting the # at the beginning of the line. Extra credit: Review the other available libreadline options.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to how you turn off the error sound for Windows, go into your Sound settings in the Windows settings. Select the  Select the "Sounds" tab. Then select the "Critical Stop" sound, and change it to "None". This will stop the terminal from making that noise. (To stop the similar sound on Windows, set the "Default Beep" sound to "None".)

Comment: This will stop ALL error sounds though

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the new Windows "Terminal" application (which is pretty slick) then you can go into `Settings > [The profile you want to change] > Advanced > Bell Notification Style` where you'll have the option to deselect "Audible" and optionally turn on "Flash window" or "Flash taskbar."